# all of my flutter code declares errors in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL9cy.png)

I am a beginner with flutter. I was using the beta version of flutter and after updating the sdk of flutter my code tells me errors and I have trouble solving them

Comment: run 'flutter doctor' command in cmd/terminal.

Comment: after execution everything is green. not error

Comment: this is warning because you not loader package or pubsec.yaml file. this will be show when clear previous build or use flutter clean..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

looks like android Studio can't find your flutter SDK.... look at Android Studio preferences -> search for flutter -> check flutter sdk path